# BIOS modification from Linux

Tags: linux, bios

I am using LFS. Is it possible to modify the BIOS settings/parameters from Linux, either in a GUI or in a command-line interface?

Comment: it is possible with _some_ (not many) motherboards/BIOSes (mostly servers though as far as I know). what is your hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I was once looking for a similar applications running on Windows or Linux in order to modify BIOS settings from Windows/Linux. This could be helpful in environments where no console access is possible (remote servers).

Unfortunately it looks like there is no generic tool which is still maintained. In fact one could edit the CMOS from Windows or Linux but this requires knowledge about data structures which depend on the BIOS and Option-ROMs used AFAIK. Therefore it would be very difficult to build a generic tool which correctly sets CMOS settings compatible to your hardware.

There used to be a software called WinBIOS which can at least perform some basic operations like restoring the default settings on Award, Ami and Phoenix. However I don't know about Linux versions.

I consider it to be quite dangerous to mess around with CMOS data from operating system without knowing the exact specification on how the data is stored (assuming that each BIOS version and brand might have different structures).

Comment: As far as, CMOS data corruption, I will go with the sandbox ( VMWare ).  In Linux, dmidecode shows the BIOS Information but not allow to modify it.

Comment: As far as I know DMI (Desktop Management Interface) is just for informational purposes. It's stored within the CMOS but contains mainly strings to identify the hardware and some settings. It's not intended to be written. I remember some ASUS boards coming with a DMI editor which allows to edit some system ID within DMI. But this is unrelated to changing BIOS settings via any external tool. I still belived there is no standard tool which works with any BIOS out there. In best case there are some tools provided by BIOS manufacturers but even they don't know all the option ROMs.